# Serialize HTML Form in JavaScript and then Convert to a .NET Type in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, serialization

I'm trying to take a HTML form and serialize the fields so that it can be stored as attributes against an element in JavaScript (you can use jQuery). This can later be parsed in C# and converted to a .NET type. This must work for any type as the form is generated via an Ajax call to the server.

For example given the following form:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Assembly" value="MyAssembly.dll" />
    <input type="text" name="Class" value="MyClass" />
    <input type="text" name="Parameters.Parameter1" value="5" />
    <input type="text" name="Parameters.Parameter2" value="10" />
</form>
```

It would produce something like:

```
<widget assembly="MyAssembly.dll" class="MyClass" parameters="???"></widget>
```

Note: ??? would be replaced with either JSON or XML (depending on your which you think is best).

Now say I stored this string in the database I need to parse it on the server to convert it to a .NET type. I can do a regular expression to get the appropriate attributes leaving me with the following variables:

```
var assembly = "MyAssembly.dll";
var @class = "MyClass";
var parameters = "???";
```

Now finally I need to serialize this to a .NET type.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks

Comment: First of all, I think this is a bad idea to expose assembly names and types into html code, it can be a major security breach... Then does the class that will hold the parameters always exist? Or do you plan to generate it?

Comment: The assembly name will only be exposed to the site admin. It will be replaced on display. The class is used as the parameters which are passed into the parameters of a ASP.NET MVC action method.

Comment: Do you really get this string from a database or do you need to get the corresponding model on the post?

Comment: The widget tag is contained within a HTML block that is stored in the database. It is generated by a plugin from a WYSIWYG Editor. This is stored in a CDN and therefore cannot use server side programming. It simply calls my API via ajax. The hard part of the problem is really the javascript side.

Comment: yep seems I don't get your problem... If the hard part is javascript why not just serialize it in json? If you already know how to get your .Net type I don't see any problem actually...

Comment: why dont you use JSON.stringify($form.serialize()) It will serialize the whole form.

Comment: Thanks Anna, that's the approach I'm playing with at the moment. Once I'm happy with my solution I'll post it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with something that works. My solution is slightly more complicated but I'll try to post the key bits in case anyone is interested.

First I created the following plugins:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(prefix) {
    var o = {};

    // Serialize the form as an array
    var a = this.serializeArray()
        .filter($.proxy(function(element) {
            // Make sure the prefix matches and it is not a checkbox (this is needed since ASP.NET MVC renders a hidden checkbox for the false value)
            return element.name.indexOf(prefix || '') == 0 && $('[name=\'' + element.name + '\'][type=\'checkbox\']', this).length == 0;
        }, this));

    // Now append the checkbox values (this makes sure we only have one element in the array with the correct value whether it is selected or not)
    a = a.concat($('input[type=\'checkbox\']', this).map(function() {
            return { 'name': this.name, 'value': $(this).is(':checked') ? 'true' : 'false' }
        }).get());

    $.each(a, function() {
        var n = this.name.substr((prefix || '').length);

        if (o[n] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[n].push)
                o[n] = [o[n]];

            o[n].push(this.value || '');
        } else
            o[n] = this.value || '';
    });

    return o;
};
```

Now for my application I actually have a WYSIWYG plugin which embeds my custom widget tag within the editor. Here's an example of what you could do to create the widget tag from the form when it is submitted (this would then be stored in the database):

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
   var parameters = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject('Parameters.'));
   var widget = '<widget assembly="' + $('[name=\'Assembly\']').val() + '" class="' + $('[name=\'Class\']').val() + '" parameters="' + parameters + '"></widget>';
   ...
});
```

Finally on the server you need to replace the widget on display by doing something like:

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"<widget assembly=""(.*?)"" class=""(.*?)"" parameters=""(.*?)""></widget>", m => ReplaceWidget(m, helper));
```

Here's the ReplaceWidget method:

```
private static string ReplaceWidget(Match match, HtmlHelper helper) {
    var assembly = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var @class = match.Groups[2].Value;
    var serializedParameters = match.Groups[3].Value;

    // Get the type
    var type = Assembly.LoadFrom(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/" + assembly)).GetType(@class);

    // Deserialize the parameters
    var parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(serializedParameters), type);

    // Return the widget
    return helper.Action("Widget", "Widgets", new { parameters = parameters }).ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps.